# SQL Server date range query not working

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to run following two SQL queries:

Take row count between `1 Oct 2014 to 31 Dec 2014`. For this I ran this query.

```
select count(*)
from table_name 
where date_column > '30-Sep-2014 23:59:59.999' and date_column < '01-Jan-2015 00:00:00.000'
```

For which I got result `28674262`

Second query is to get row count between `1 Jul 2014 to 31 Sep 2014` for which I ran following query.

```
select count(*)
from table_name
WHERE date_column > '30-Jun-2014 23:59:59.999' and date_column < '01-Oct-2014 00:00:00.000'
```

and I got this result : `28296043`

Now to get the row count for `1 Jul 2014 to 31 Dec 2014` time period I ran following query.

```
select count(*)
from table_name 
WHERE date_column > '30-Jun-2014 23:59:59.999' and date_column < '01-Jan-2015 00:00:00.000'
```

This query is giving result `57361505`.

If I add result of 1st and second query, it should give the same row count as 3rd query, that is `57361505` but I am getting `28674262` + `28296043` = `56970305`

I would like to know why there is difference between row counts? Is there anything wrong with my queries?

Comment: No. In third query I am looking for row count between Jul to December.

Comment: Are you getting this same difference on second run as well?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You would seem to have some records, say 200, where the date is between '30-Sep-2014 23:59:59.999' and '01-Oct-2014 00:00:00.000'.  This is possible depending on the types of the date/time values.

Get rid of the time stamps!  They are just confusing things.  Use these conditions:

```
where date_column >= '2014-10-01' and date_column < '2015-01-01'
where date_column >= '2014-07-01' and date_column < '2014-10-01'
where date_column >= '2014-07-01' and date_column < '2015-01-01'
```

In general, when using dates, use comparisons on the date with no time component and use inequality conditions where appropriate.

Also notice that I switched to an ISO standard date formats.

Comment: Thanks. I'll try this way

Comment: This approach worked. Now row counts are matching correctly. I wonder what can be the date time between 30-Sep-2014 23:59:59.999' and '01-Oct-2014 00:00:00.000'.

Comment: Maybe you are using `datetime2` datatype? More info [here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb677335(v=sql.105).aspx). This format stores `19 positions minimum (YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss ) to 27 maximum (YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss.0000000)`

Answer (score 1):

Try below query and let me know what count it returns.

```
select count(*) from table_name 
WHERE date_column >= '01-Jul-2014' and date_column <= '31-Dec-2014 23:59:59:999'
```

Comment: Thanks for helping me out on weekend :) I ran this query but I got row count as '57771746'. Can you please check if there is anything wrong in my logic? Am I expecting correct thing?

Comment: do one thing if you have excel then get all records in excel and count there with date range and compare count to your query and also try query as i explain and see which query gives you count matching with excel

Answer (score 1):

There must be some null values in date_column, Also Count That

```
select count(*)
from table_name 
WHERE isnull(date_column ,'') = ''
```